# Retrieve user information from Web API OAuth Bearer authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a working Web API using Token validation but I want to retrieve the user who sent that token.

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.Name; // returns null
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use **owin** and get the current user this way

```
ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
```

to check if it is authenticated

```
ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Be sure the username is linked to the token this way (it is on my

> SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

class)

```
 ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
```

Comment: ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name; is returning null, even though IsAuthenticated is true. Do you know what I could be missing? Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you added the username to the Claims?, I edited my answer

Comment: That was it! I was not aware that we have to fill the name property with claims. Thank you!